# How to validate the results of pathlib.glob?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting a FileNotFoundError when trying to iterate over a pathlib.glob() result.  The exception is raised on the `for` line, so I can't iterate over it to validate the paths with something like `os.stat()`.  To wrap it with `try`/`except`, I'd have to wrap the whole `for` loop, failing out of the whole operation as soon as I hit a bad path.

Example code.  This `try`/`except` doesn't catch the error.

```
import hashlib
import pathlib

search_path_root = pathlib.Path("F:\\searchpathroot\\")
paths = search_path_root.glob("**/*.jpg")

for path in paths:
    try:
        with open(path,"rb") as hash_file:
            hash_file_contents = hash_file.read()
        md5_sum = hashlib.md5(hash_file_contents).hexdigest()
        print("{} | {}".format(md5_sum,path))
    except:
        pass
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 7, in <module>
    for path in paths:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pathlib.py", line 1136, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pathlib.py", line 583, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pathlib.py", line 530, in _select_from
    with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:\\searchpathroot\\broken\\filename'
```

I have also tried casting the generator to a list, which threw the same exception:

```
...
paths = search_path_root.glob("**/*.jpg")
paths = list(paths)

for path in paths:
...
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 5, in <module>
    paths = list(paths)
...
```

To be clear, I know what is causing this particular exception (it's being raised when Windows tries to access a backup of a recovered encrypted Linux partition--whole other can of worms, heh).  What I'm trying to figure out is how to properly validate pathlib.glob() paths in general.

Comment: for me your code not throwing any excpetion

Comment: What i don't understand why `Path.glob()` find the files that doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Yeah, the exception is caused by an issue at the OS level--there's recovered encrypted data on the disk that Windows can't access (again, whole unrelated can of worms).  


The fact that there's an exception is almost tangential to the question.  I can fix this specific exception by excluding the path that has issues, but that's a workaround that doesn't robust my code.  What I want to figure out is how to *generally* validate the results of pathlib.glob().

Comment: can you be more specific what do you mean by "how to generally validate the results of pathlib.glob()"?

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to catch exceptions related to invalid paths like this without stopping all execution if there is an invalid path present in the entirety of the results.  Currently, if there is one path that is invalid for any reason in ```paths```, I get the above exception immediately when the ```for``` loop accesses ```paths```, such that I get no results at all.  In this particular case, that exception is this OS filesystem access error, but it could notionally be caused by any number of weird edge cases like that, which I'd like to be able to gracefully handle.

Comment: try converting `pahs` to list and then access it using index

Comment: Ah, I did try that and got the same exception.  I'll edit the OP to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `pathlib.glob` doesn't allow you to add custom error handling, so as soon as a bad spot is hit on the filesystem (e.g. broken symlink), it will raise and abort.

A more flexible alternative is [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

```py
import os

def report_error(ex):
    print(f'Error scanning {ex.filename}: {ex}')

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('f:/searchpathroot', onerror=report_error):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            abs_filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            # do something with abs_filename
```

Comment: Looks like this will work for this case, thanks.  I poked around in the pathlib docs looking for something like custom error handling... I hoped I was just missing it.